# Inconsistent storage class specifiers on functions

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I have

```
static void static_func(void);
void static_func(void) { }
static inline void static_inline_func(void);
void static_inline_func(void) { }

#if 0 //error
    void extern_func(void){}
    static void extern_func(void);
#endif

int main()
{
    static_func();
    static_inline_func();
}
```

I was expecting warnings or errors but neither gcc nor clang are making any, even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Is this conformant C? Why or why not?

Comment: I'm not an expert in `C`, but I didn't see why it should have errors/warinings...

Comment: Why are you expecting errors?

Comment: I assume the expected errors have to do with the mismatch between the function prototypes and definitions.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Both the declarations and the definitions have prototypes, and they match.

Comment: @Rakete1111 `static int foo; int foo;` is an error. Why shouldn't  `static int foo(); int foo();` or `static int foo(); int foo(){}` be as well?

Comment: @PSkocik Try `static int foo; extern int foo;`.

Comment: IIRC absence of storage class specifier in a function declaration means "extern if not previously declared otherwise".  So nothing is really inconsistent here (outside of `#if 0`).

Comment: *"Is this conformant C?"* - Yes. *"Why?"* - Because it follows the C standard.

Comment: *Why shouldn't* for [hysterical raisins](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html).

Comment: Note. I did not mean to be condescending. It's just that it's almost impossible to explain why a code snippet is valid. It is simply valid because it follow all the rules.

Comment: @Broman LOL. I guess I shouldn't be tagging language-lawyer without language-lawyer-proofing the question first. :D

Comment: @PSkocik Hehe. It's much easier to explain why code is NOT valid. A not so far fetched comparison is Russell's teapot. :)

Comment: @Broman: It is not at all impossible to explain why a code snippet is valid. There are formal specifications of how a machine may parse text according to a grammar, so a mathematical proof that the grammar is satisfied can be given by showing the steps a machine goes through to accept the text. The semantic rules are less formalized but can still be explained by stating which rules apply to which parts of the text and by stating relationships between them, as well as explaining the rules in more colloquial language or by expounding on their technical concepts.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I wrote "almost" and I think you understood what I meant. Showing why something is not valid C is much easier than showing that it is. If something is invalid C it can often be explained with a single sentence.

Comment: @Broman: It is not almost impossible. In general, it is not close to almost impossible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm sorry, but I will not go into another discussion with you where the main issue is formal logic vs casual language. Have a good day.

Comment: @Broman: And yet people explain the validity of code snippets all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding:

```
static void static_func(void);
void static_func(void) { }
```

For the first line, C 2018 6.2.2 3 says:

> If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.

For the second line, 6.2.2 5 says:

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`.…

so we refer to the paragraph about when `extern` is specified, 6.2.2 4 (emphasis added):

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` **in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,** if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration.…

Thus, since the prior declaration is visible, `void static_funct(void)` is equivalent to `static void static_funct(void)`.

(Note that 6.2.2 5 differs for objects; after the portion quoted above, it goes on to say “If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.” Thus `static int x; int x;` creates a conflict for the object `x`, whereas `static int f(void); int f(void);` does not create a conflict for the function `f`.)

Regarding:

```
static inline void static_inline_func(void);
void static_inline_func(void) { }
```

`inline` is a function specifier, not a storage-class specifier, and 6.7.4 6 tells us:

> A function declared with an `inline` function specifier is an *inline function*.…

As we saw above, `void static_inline_func(void) { }` still has internal linkage, due to the prior declaration. 6.7.4 7 is quite lax about the requirements on inline functions with internal linkage:

> Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function.…

Had the function not be declared with `static`, there are further restrictions in 6.7.4 7:

> For a function with external linkage, the following restrictions apply: If a function is declared with an `inline` function specifier, then it shall also be defined in the same translation unit. If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the `inline` function specifier without `extern`, then the definition in that translation unit is an inline definition. An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function, and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit. An inline definition provides an alternative to an external definition, which a translator may use to implement any call to the function in the same translation unit.…

(It is not clear where the text covered by “the following restrictions apply” ends.)

Thus, there may be both an inline definition of a function and an external definition (in another translation unit). In either case, there do not appear to be any prohibitions on declaring a function both with and without `inline`; there are merely implications to doing so, notably that declaring an external function both with and without `inline` means the definition in that translation unit is not an inline definition.

Comment: Clarification: there may be both an inline definition and an external definition of the same function identifier in the same program, but *not in the same translation unit*.  Moreover, in the example code, the definition of `static_inline_func` is *not* an inline definition, because not all of the declarations in that TU bear the `inline` specifier.

Comment: I know the difference between an external definition and an identifier with external linkage.  From the perspective of the standard, you cannot have both an inline and and external definition of the same function identifier in the same TU because function definitions must appear at file scope, they provide declarations, and a function definition is an inline definition only if *all* file-scope declarations of that identifier in the TU have the `inline` specifier.  If they do then there can be only an inline definition.  If they don't then there can be only an external one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Interestingly, empirically I can do `inline void extern_inline_func(void);
void extern_inline_func(void) { }` in both gcc and clang (my patched tinycc--though I wasn't particularly aiming to support this) and it creates an externally visible symbol. From looking at the standard, it looks like it shouldn't.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Updated. Where you do think the text meant by “the following restrictions” ends? It is not just the next sentence, because that is just one restriction, not restrictions. But I am not sure it is the entire rest of the paragraph either.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Looked into it some more: Apparently "all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit " in [6.7.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.4p7)  includes function declarations at least CompilerExplorer's C99 compilers (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WFMSv5) are interpreting it like that. It should be a valid interpretation too given that external-declarations are defined to include function-definitions [6.9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I think "the following restrictions" end at the end of the sentence.  So in particular, if a function identifier is declared with internal linkage then that paragraph does not require a definition of it to appear in the TU, but if one *does* appear in the TU then it is an inline definition if and only if all the file-scope declarations of that function in the TU carry the `inline` specifier.

Comment: Yes, @PSkocik, if even one file-scope declaration of your a function in a given TU omits the `inline` specifier, then the definition of that function within, if any, is an external definition, not an inline one.  Therefore, if it has external linkage, then one would expect there to be an externally-visible symbol associated with it.  The only effect of `inline` in that case is that it "suggests that calls to the function be as fast as possible."  Also, the standard is clear that "**A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier** that [...]." Functions are not excepted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is valid C.

The following standard references are from C99, but the C17 draft contains exactly the same text.

6.2.2 (Linkages of identifiers) says:

> 4. For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior
>      declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.
> 5. If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`.

Thus: `extern` doesn't always mean external linkage. If there is an existing declaration with internal linkage (`static`) visible in the current scope, that's what takes precedence.

However, 6.11 (Future language directions) also says:

> **6.11.2 Linkages of identifiers**
>
> 1. Declaring an identifier with internal linkage at file scope without the `static` storage-class specifier is an obsolescent feature.

So while this is a valid feature of C, you probably shouldn't rely on it in new code.

Comment: Note that it is not an **existing** declaration that affects the later declaration, but a **visible** declaration. This matters where there is a different declaration in an intervening scope, which we have seen some questions about in Stack Overflow. (Like `static void x(void); … { int x; { extern void x(void);… } }`.)

Answer (score 2):

Quote from [`6.2.2  Linkagesof identifiers p4`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which prior declaration of that identifier is visible,23)if the prior declaration specifies internal or external  linkage,  the  linkage  of  the  identifier  at  the  later  declaration  is  the  same  as  the linkage specified at the prior declaration.
>
> If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage

So, in these 2 cases the 2nd declaration is correct, and the linkage is static (the 2nd declaration is external by default):

```
static void static_func(void);
void static_func(void) { }

static inline void static_inline_func(void);
void static_inline_func(void) { }
```

Quote from p7, same chapter:

> If,  within  a  translation  unit,  the  same  identifier  appears  with  both  internal  and  externallinkage, the behavior is undefined

So, declaring it like this is undefined behavior.

```
#if 0 //error
    void extern_func(void){}
    static void extern_func(void);
#endif
```

Comment: Your quote doesn't apply to the code in question. The quote says "*For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`*", but there is no `extern` in the code.

Comment: @melpomene thanks -- the default linkage is external, I added the definition of no storage class specifier